# jquery " :input" selector difficulties

Tags: jquery, forms, input, selector, onsubmit

i have the following code:

```
<h3> Your Profile </h3>
The information below is what we have on file for you.

<form id="profileform" name="profileform" action=""> 
<table>

<?php
$profile_array = select_profile_data($_SESSION['id']);
while (list($key, $value) = each($profile_array)) {
if(!in_array($key,$dont_display_list,true)) {
 echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td><td><input type="text" name=' . $key . ' value="'.$value.'"</td></tr>';
}
}
?>
</table>
<input type="button" value="submit changes" name="submit" onClick="button_click('profileform')">
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function button_click(formname) {
var fullselect = formname + " :input";
alert(fullselect);
var values = $(fullselect);
alert(values.size());
$("#content").html('<span>Loading...</span>');
$("#content").load('profile.php', values, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#content").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

my alert at "fullselect" shows me the expected jquery selector string 'profileform :input'. However, my "values" variable always returns a size of "0". While there are definitely "input variables" in the form. Any thoughts on where i'm going wrong here?

thanks,

Comment: to select an input within a form, your selector can be $(formname + ' input'). You don't need the colon for that

Comment: @Kristian `input` and `:input` are not the same. `:input` will select `input`, `textarea`, `button` and `select` elements. `input`, just gets `input`. http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: ah, I stand corrected, thanks for the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `#` from the start of the `formname` variable, as it is the `id` of the form:

```
var fullselect = "#" + formname + " :input";
```

Also, the `values` variable will be an array of jQuery objects, so it won't be valid for you to pass accross to your PHP using the `load()` method. The best thing to do is to `serialize()` the entire form and pass that:

```
var values = $(fullselect).serialize();
```